# Java: Get class type of return object of generic supplier

Tags: java, generics, reflection, supplier

Let's assume the following definition is given:

```
final Supplier<MyClass> supplier = MyClass::new;
```

Is there a way I can get `MyClass.class` without actually invoking `.get()` on the supplier?

Why? I have to know the specified class to make some logical decisions. Based on this, I might need to find another constructor in `MyClass` which has a parameter and the only knowledge I have of the target class is a supplier of this type. Of course I could just invoke `.get()` and go from there, like this:

```
final MyClass obj = supplier.get().getClass().getConstructor(MyParameter.class).newInstance(..);
```

But using this before doing my intermediate steps might result in an unnecessary object creation

Comment: Type erasure... You can't get to `MyClass` from `supplier`. Maybe sharing more context on your code (full method, etc) can lead to alternative approaches...

Comment: If you want to get `Class<MyClass>`, why isn't your supplier defined as `Supplier<Class<MyClass>>` then?

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Comment: @DiegoMarin I have seen this post but that would require refactoring on my side, something I'm trying to avoid.
@Thomas because the supplier is actually used in this form, I just figured I might aswell use the supplier to get the information instead of refactoring a whole bunch of code.
@ernest_k we have a base class `A` and a few sub-classes `A1`, `A2` and `A3`. In addion to that we have an advanced `enum` which mappes certain entries to those classes. e.g. `ENUM1("my first enum", A1::new)`, `ENUM2("some more stuff", A2::new)`.

Comment: at the point in the code where I'm at currently I only have an instance of `A` (could be any of `A1`, `A2`, ..). I can only get an `enum` representing the actuall subclass from this `A`-object. My goal is to create an object of the subclass (e.g. `A2`) from this `A` object by invoking an `A2` constructor and passing `A` as a delegate to recreate a specific object. all this is for some edgecase with hibernate proxy objects I'm trying to circumnavigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like below. It is necessary to add Guava as a dependency.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;

public abstract class MySupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {

  private final TypeToken<T> typeToken = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) { };
  private final Type type = typeToken.getType();

  public Type getType() {
    return type;
  }
}

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Supplier<String> supplier = new MySupplier<String>() {
      @Override
      public String get() {
        return new String();
      }
    };
    System.out.println(((MySupplier) supplier).getType());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together, but this seems like an overkill. I'd rather extend my `enum`s to carry the necessary information

Comment: I guess the overall gist is, it isn't possible.